# hhvm memcached cas being unset

Tags: php, memcached, hhvm

I have a pretty large application that I am currently running with PHP (without any issues). I'm attempting to run it using hhvm. In PHP obviously it runs fine. The application reads data from a socket, and then does a bunch of stuff. It spawns concurrent threads for performance sake.

The error I am seeing is:
Fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Memcached::cas() must be an instance of float, null given

The way it works is that on the first iteration, it works fine. cas is set to a value and the iteration works as it should. Every subsequent iteration fails due to the error given above. It seems like it's just being unset, but I don't really understand why. Is there something specific I'm supposed to do differently with hhvm than I would normally do with PHP?

```
function mc_get($var, $thread_id=-1)
{
    if (empty($var))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $_lock = (int)$this->mc->get('lock_' . $var, NULL, $_cas);

    if ($_lock === 0)
    {
        // the line below is where the error occurs
        $this->mc->cas($_cas, 'lock_' . $var, 1);
        if ($this->mc->getResultCode() != Memcached::RES_SUCCESS)
        {
            $this->log(4, "[$thread_id] SPINLOCK(1) on $var" . function_trace() . "\n");
        }
    }

    $r = $this->mc->get($var);
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: " switch from PHP to hhvm" um no your not

Comment: Thanks for the completely useless reply pointing out a completely irrelevant semantic issue. I've gone ahead and changed the post to be more clear in case it wasn't already clear enough for you.

Comment: well I guess you wont like me pointing out that $_cas is null then; its not defined in the function, or passed into it.

Comment: @Dagon You might be interested in [this mailing list discussion](http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=140623278028465&w=2); that particular post is from [Zeev Suraski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeev_Suraski), co-author of PHP3; opinions differed, but no consensus was reached on any name *other than* "PHP" for the reference distribution.

Comment: This line grabs the 'lock' . $var variable from memcached, and WRITES it to $_cas.
`$_lock = (int)$this->mc->get('lock_' . $var, NULL, $_cas);`

This line uses the variable that was written to above.
`$this->mc->cas($_cas, 'lock_' . $var, 1);`

As I mentioned in my initial post, the code works fine using php.

Comment: out of curiosity, is `$_cas` set (in `->get(` ) when the key is non_existent ?